# How to force cmake put options after filename?

Tags: gcc, linker, cmake

By some reason the following do now work

```
/usr/bin/c++  -lm -L/usr/X11R6/lib  -lX11 -lpthread  CMakeFiles/net.dir/advanced.cpp.o   -o net -rdynamic
```

But this do:

```
/usr/bin/c++  -lm -L/usr/X11R6/lib   CMakeFiles/net.dir/advanced.cpp.o  -lX11 -lpthread  -o net -rdynamic
```

My question is how to force CMake to put option AFTER /advanced.cpp.o to make compilation possible in my case. All CMake options I used put my custom GCC option before compiler.

My cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (mnist)

set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )

add_compile_options("-O2")
add_compile_options("-std=c++11")

SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11")

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(net advanced.cpp)
```

Comment: What's your minimal CMakeLists.txt to get this command? Some commands have AFTER/BEFORE statement.

Comment: I tried to use SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11")

Comment: You should use `add_library` instead.

Comment: From https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html:
adds a library target called <name> to be built from the source files listed in the command invocation. How this supposed to help me?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant `target_link_libraries`

Comment: Aside from using `target_link_libraries` instead of `-l` option in linker flags, as noted by usr1234567, it is better to use `link_directories` instead of `-L` option in linker flags.

Comment: It helped thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `target_link_libraries` instead of adding `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.
And use `link_directories` instead of `-L` option in linker flags.